# creating column family in cql?

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, cql

when i create column family using the cql it gives me very unexpected output.

```
public static void createColumnfamily()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.32:9160/temp");
            String qry = "CREATE TABLE users(user_name varchar," +
                                            "password varchar," +
                                            "gender varchar," +
                                            "session_token varchar," +
                                            "birth_year bigint," +
                                            "PRIMARY KEY (user_name)" +
                                            ")";
            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            smt.executeUpdate(qry);
            System.out.println("TABLE(column family) is created");
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Here what i got : line 1:132 extraneous input ')' expecting EOF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using CQL 2, which does not support that style of primary key declaration. If you want to declare it that way, you should be using CQL 3, which you can accomplish by requesting that version in the connection URL:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.32:9160/temp?version=3.0.0");
```

However, CQL 3 isn't necessary just for this. As Steve Van Opstal suggested, you can simply put the `PRIMARY KEY` marker with the column definition itself, since you don't have a multi-component primary key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    password varchar,
    gender varchar,
    session_token varchar,
    birth_year bigint,
);
```

CQL 3 is to be generally preferred if your Cassandra supports it, as it is the way forward, but in case you don't want to switch right now, you can make that second change.

Answer (score 1):

I only see two possible problems here.

1. The query doesn't accept your way of defining the primary key

   Try this:

   ```
       String qry = "CREATE TABLE users(user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY," +
                                       "password varchar," +
                                       "gender varchar," +
                                       "session_token varchar," +
                                       "birth_year bigint"
                                       ")";
   ```
2. The query doesn't accept varchar's as primary key

   Try this:

   ```
       String qry = "CREATE TABLE users(user_id int" +
                                       "user_name varchar," +
                                       "password varchar," +
                                       "gender varchar," +
                                       "session_token varchar," +
                                       "birth_year bigint," +
                                       "PRIMARY KEY (user_id)" +
                                       ")";
   ```